# How to set constraints based on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to display a button as per the image below.  It's width and height are determined by a XIB that this button is a subview of (that's not really important information for this issue though).

The constraints are setup for the "SkipBreak" button in Interface Builder.

[image]

You can't tell from the image I've attached, but there is a transport bar located beneath the button.  The alignment of the button relative to the transport bar is fine if I test on an iPad (in either portrait or landscape orientation).  But if I test on an iPhone (such as the XR model) in landscape mode, the button ends up overlapping the transport bar.

[image]

Is there is a way I can set the constraints of this button so that the anchor point from the leading and bottom edges of the superview differ based on the device?

Is this what size classes are for? If so, is there a resource you can point me to in order to figure out how to do this?

Otherwise, do I have to delete the constraints programmatically, check the device type and then add the constraints?

Comment: You _might_ be able to do this with size classes; it depends whether the location of the transport corresponds to the size classes (it might). If not, you don't have to delete and add. The constraint has a value, its `constant`. You can change that in code, depending on where you think the transport will be. But in any case, first, your job is to figure out where the transport is on every device in every orientation.

Comment: @matt I took your advice and created outlets for the leading and bottom constraints and then adjusted the constant value.  A problem that I noticed is that the button is perfectly aligned on an iPhone XR but is too high on an iPhone SE.

Comment: It doesn't make sense why the same bottom constraint constant would make the button appear in different positions on 2 different iPhones?

Comment: Yes, like I said, you'd have to determine experimentally what the values should be, since the transport is out of your process.

Comment: "It doesn't make sense why the same bottom constraint constant would make the button appear in different positions on 2 different iPhones?" Well, it depends what the constraint is _to_. And of course I don't know if the transport itself appears in the same place on both.

Comment: @matt The bottom constraint is to the superview.bottom.

Comment: Well, that would remain the same on both devices, you'd expect. But as I say, the transport itself could be in a different place. And that would not surprise me. The iPhone XR has no bezel, and it has a curvy screen, so I would expect the transport to be higher, away from the curvy part. It is probably positioned with respect to the _safe area_. But your constraint is not. Set your constraint with respect to the safe area and see if that makes things more consistent.